# Microsoft VBA Runtime 1004 Error, Application-defined or object-defined error, filling 2 columns at once

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to get this line of code working:

`Worksheets("Pro-ration").Cells(row, 3) = 0`

I'm using it to try to fill a C column with zeros, up until the loop it is inside stops. The loop is:

```
Do Until DateAdd("d", 1, startdate) = enddate + 1
    Activecell.Offset(row, 0).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, startdate)
    startdate = startdate + 1
    Worksheets("Pro-ration").Cells(row, 3) = 0
    row = row + 1
Loop
```

The goal is to keep filling a column C with corresponding zero values as column B is filled in with dates. Column B is filled correctly with dates when the bolded line is not added. However, now that I have added the line, when I run this, I get a 1004 error, Application-defined or object-defined error.

What about the line of code is triggering this? How can I fix it? Is there some more straightforward way of entering values into a column while there are still corresponding values in the rows of the column next to it? Thank you, sorry if this is a tedious question but I am very new to VBA. Thank you!

Comment: Probably `row` = `0` on the first iteration... there's no row 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise `row = 1` (or any value greater than 1) before trying to use it (place it before the `Do Until`).

Maybe it's already written before the code sample, but then you should edit your code to include it. Otherwise people trying to help you might waste usefull comments.

Comment: My apologies then, I though writing ```.Value``` was mandatory to modify cell's value.

Comment: Indeed, tested the simpliest code and feeling like a fool now. Should I delete my answer ?

Comment: No problem, I've edited the answer and I'm thankful for the reminder.